# What am I? Yet another rhyming Riley

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is sufficient, just meeting expectation.
>
> My infix is a call to arms that condemns hesitation.
>
> My suffix is a next of kin, a term that's so endeared.
>
> My whole, I think, will leave you stunned, a status to be feared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it:

> paralysis?

My prefix is sufficient, just meeting expectation.

> Par

My infix is a call to arms that condemns hesitation.

> Ra(l)ly?

My suffix is a next of kin, a term that's so endeared.

> Sis (for sister)

My whole, I think, will leave you stunned, a status to be feared.

> Paralysis

Comment: I really am making these far too easy.